# Do you train on dev sets before obtaining test performance for academic papers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

For hackathons or some shared task events, people train their models on dev sets as well to obtain the highest test performance possible.

However, I am unclear if this practice is the norm for test performances reported on academic papers as well. Specifically, for BERT's paper, they report test set results on the GLUE benchmark. I want to know if BERT was trained on train + dev or train only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Training on train + dev (or test) set is not a common practice in academic papers. In [BERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) paper, authors clearly distinguish between the test and the training sets (e.g. Table 1).